# Validate a user's geolocation when the user posts data to a webpage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, geolocation

I’d like to have a form on a website that can only be submitted if the user has permitted the page to get the users location via HTML5's Geolocation. When the form is submitted I'd like those coordinates to be passed along with the rest of the information.

However, I want to prevent people from being able to just write their own code to post fake data with latitude and longitude information. I'd like to have some sort of authentication that the coordinates being sent correspond to the user's geolocation.

Is this possible? What methods for validating/signing the coordinates sent from the client (webpage) to the server? How would you go about this?

In case someone needs more specifics, the website itself will be a Ruby app and the form's submit button is really just making a REST call via POST to a URL.

Comment: You can't prevent users submitting a form (or at least sending data that looks exactly like a submitted form). You can't enforce geolocation. You can validate that the values are within certain bounds (if they are provided), but you can't guarantee that they represent where the user is actually located.

Comment: @RobG What about something like this. When the page is request it creates a token/random string and passes that along with an ajax request on the document's ready event like apneadiving suggested. Then the page itself could use one of those images with distorted characters (what's their proper name?) that a user needs to manually type in. The users response will also be sent with the same token as the location was sent with and if correct, it validates that token and trusts the coordinates? (I'm just looking to make it complicated to game, not impossible.) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Beware:

- the browser may not handle HTML5 geolocation
- the user of the website can refuse the geolocation

If the user accepts geolocation you should send the data directly via ajax otherwise the javascript variables could be changed client-side.

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  //try to retrieve user's position
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     //put ajax request here and send (position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
    },
    function() {
    //failure: the user refused
    }
  );
}
else {
  //failure but the navigator doesn't handle geolocation
}
```

Comment: Using AJAX doesn't prevent users from modifying the values (or sending whatever values they want) on the client.

Comment: @RobG: of course but because data are sent directly once user accepts geocoding there is no point in changing js variables afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not clear on how your method validates the coordinates as coming from geolocation running in the clients browser. How would the server know if the ajax request was made from my website's ready event, and not from another location with bogus values?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of validating 100% that the data sent your server has not been altered. The user may easily use the browser's console or a simple curl request to send whatever he wants.

**You have to think it like this**: you are basically asking the user *where are you?* and the user is using his browser to help him find his location, but in the end the user is be able to send any data to your server.

The only thing I can think of would be to **verify that the IP address location is somewhere close to the latitude/longitude sent**, using some website like this one: http://www.ip2location.com/1.2.3.4

But anyway, that would not be 100% safe because if a user wants to mess with your server then he could just use a proxy to set a different IP address.